# Return both text and inline r markdown from within a function

Tags: r, r-markdown

Uses:

```
install.packages("bookdown")
library(bookdown)
```

GitHub: https://github.com/MartinJLambert/r-markdown_function_test

Given that I need to reproduce these values multiple times within the same document, I have created a function that calculates a simple ANOVA and determines the F, df, p and n statistics, as well as an asterix indicator for significance based on the p-value.

````
---
  output:
    bookdown::pdf_document2
---
```{r include= FALSE}
# function for calculating and displaying statistics results from an ANOVA
func_aov_stats <- function(input_df, input_var, input_factor) {
  aov_tmp <- aov(input_var ~ input_factor, input_df)
  anova_tmp <- anova(aov_tmp)
  
  temp_signif <- if(anova_tmp[1,5] < 0.001){print("***")}
    else if(anova_tmp[1,5] < 0.01){print("**")}
    else if(anova_tmp[1,5] <0.05){print("*")}
    else {print("")}
  
  paste(anova_tmp[1,1], anova_tmp[1,4], anova_tmp[1,5], temp_signif, anova_tmp[2,1]+2)
}
```

`r func_aov_stats(mtcars, mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)`
````

This is simple enough and knitting this does exactly what I want it to do.

> 1 79.5610275293349 6.11268714258098e-10 *** 32

However, numbers alone are kinda useless, so I would like to report it as a string of text. Something along these lines:

> ANOVA: F<sub>(df=***anova_tmp[1,1]***)</sub> = ***anova_tmp[1,4]***, p
> = ***anova_tmp[1,5] temp_signif***, n = ***anova_tmp[2,1]+2***

I was thinking of simply pasting the inline r-markdown inside the function:

```
paste("ANOVA: F~(df=`r anova_tmp[1,1]`)~ = `r anova_tmp[1,4]`, p = `r paste(anova_tmp[1,5] temp_signif)`, n = `r anova_tmp[2,1]+2`")
```

But I get this:

> ANOVA: F<sub>(df=r anova_tmp[1,1])</sub> = r anova_tmp[1,4], p = r anova_tmp[1,5] temp_signif, n = r anova_tmp[2,1]+2

At least the markdown formatting worked, but it obviously doesn't paste the `'r'` components as hoped.

What *does* work, is if I write it out manually outside of the function, elsewhere in the markdown document:

````
```{r outside_of_function, include= FALSE}
aov_tmp <- aov(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)
anova_tmp <- anova(aov_tmp)

temp_signif <- if(anova_tmp[1,5] < 0.001){print("***")} else if(anova_tmp[1,5] < 0.01){print("**")} else if(anova_tmp[1,5] <0.05){print("*")} else {print("")}
```

ANOVA: F~(df=`r anova_tmp[1,1]`)~ = `r anova_tmp[1,4]`, p = `r paste(anova_tmp[1,5], temp_signif)`, n = `r anova_tmp[2,1]+2`
````

> ANOVA: F<sub>(df=1)</sub> = 79.5610275, p = 6.11268714258098e-10 ***, n = 32

So the issue is within the function itself. While it does seem to be able to produce the formatting, the computation of the `'r'` code seems to require something beyond my understanding.

Comment: Inside paste you can combine text and variables as: paste(“ANOVA: F~(df=“, anova_tmp[1,1], “)~ =“, anova_tmp[1,4], ...) and so on. Perhaps that works?

Comment: @loreabad6 It does print out the code, yes, but the formatting doesn't work with this, unfortunately. The issue now is that it is displayed as:  F~(df= 1 )~ = ... etc.
When writing "F~(df= 1 )~ =" in markdown, the same thing happens. However, when you remove the spaces within the subscript tildes to "F~(df=1)~ =" it works as it should.
So, the solution (perhaps) is to get this code to not place spaces between each test/variable. I tried removing all spaces before and after commas, but that didn't help.

Comment: @loreabad6 Worked it out! paste0() removes the gaps! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure, happy it worked @Martin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is: paste0().

Full code, updated and fully functioning:

````
---
  output:
    bookdown::pdf_document2
---
```{r include = FALSE}
# function for calculating and displaying statistics results from an ANOVA
func_aov_stats <- function(input_df, input_var, input_factor) {
  aov_tmp <- aov(input_var ~ input_factor, input_df)
  anova_tmp <- anova(aov_tmp)
  
  temp_signif <- if(anova_tmp[1,5] < 0.001){print("***")}
  else if(anova_tmp[1,5] < 0.01){print("**")}
  else if(anova_tmp[1,5] <0.05){print("*")}
  else {print("")}
  
  paste0("ANOVA: F~(df=",anova_tmp[1,1],")~= ",anova_tmp[1,4],", p = ",anova_tmp[1,5]," ",temp_signif," n = ",anova_tmp[2,1]+2)
}
```

`r func_aov_stats(mtcars, mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)`
````