# Get a kable output from an R function

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I have an Rmd script where I want to display tables for different attributes of a dataset. I wrote this (here shorted) function to save some work:

```r
attr_table <- function(name, attr) {
   table_attr <- table(attr)
   
   kable(table_attr,
         caption = name,
         col.names = "Frequency")
   barplot(table_attr, horiz = TRUE)
}
```

When I now call it like `attr_table("Name", vector)` an knit the file, the barplot is there, but not the table.

So the question is: Can I use `kable()` inside a function or does it have to be on itself every time?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit odd, but you can try something like this:

```
attr_table <- function(name, attr) {
   table_attr <- table(attr)
   print(knitr::kable(table_attr,
         caption = name,
         col.names = c("Name","Frequency")))
   barplot(table_attr, horiz = TRUE)
}
```

Notice that a function returns the last evaluated statement and also that you were missing one col.name.

Comment: I had two col.names originally, but that gave me the error `length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`. With only one it works

Comment: If I add the `print()`I get an output, however not the pretty table I was going for, but this: https://imgur.com/a/pwkTQNT

Edit: Included a screenshot as multiline code formatting doesn't work in comments

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault as I didn't realize you were on a markdown context. This must e handeled in a different fashion. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656400/return-both-text-and-inline-r-markdown-from-within-a-function